# Why is missing the carriage return?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a SQL command that is updating a field into a table and populate this based on a "cat file.txt". This file as a lot of lines and I would like later to have into the hibernate field but seems that after reading it from db hibernate remove all carriage return.

This is the script I execute from shell script(bash):

```
 REQUEST_FILE=`cat file.txt`
 echo "UPDATE table SET request_info='$REQUEST_FILE'  WHERE id=1;" > ./after.sql
```

if I do cat of the after.sql I get:

```
 UPDATE table SET request_info='1-Start-Env Script for Env
 2-insert done
 3-update info done
 4-all performed correctly'  WHERE id=29;
```

this is the DB table structure:

```
Table: table
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
submit_date datetime 
request_type varchar(45) 
request_info longtext
```

this is the data stored on db and how is the row:

```
# id, submit_date,request_type, request_info
'29', '2019-02-11 04:55:21', 'check', '1-Start-Env Script for Env\n2-insert done\n3-update info done\n4-all performed correctly'
```

So till this step I guess all is ok as field is containing the '\n'

Hibernate class is done in this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table")
@NamedQuery(name="Table.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Table u")
public class Table implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   @Column(name="request_info")
   private String requestInfo;

   @Column(name="request_type")
   private String requestType;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   @Column(name="submit_date")
   private Date submitDate;
```

and when I access to the requestInfo variable the output is:

> 1-Start-Env Script for Env2-insert done3-update info done4-all performed correctly

This variable is used to create a file after clicking a button from a JSF page:

```
  HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) 
  fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

     output.write(request.getRequestInfo().getBytes());

    output.flush();
    output.close();
```

If i do the System.out I see correct data, then I guess is the getBytes function is not returning the carriage return:

```
         System.out.println("file content:" +request.getRequestInfo());
```

Output:

```
file content:1-Start-Env Script for Env 
2-insert done 
3-update info done 
4-all performed correctly
```

do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: is the `requestInfo` variable outputted with `System.out.println` or in a browser window?

Comment: @ValentinCarnu i updated the topic, i'm getting the value and do getBytes and writing the output as attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the newline character.

Instead of `\n`, use `\r\n` for your new line in the file.

However, this will not fix the issue on all platforms, only the one you're testing on.

See here for more info on newlines and different platforms:

https://superuser.com/questions/374028/how-are-n-and-r-handled-differently-on-linux-and-windows

You can also try something like:

`output.write(request.getRequestInfo().replaceAll("(\\\\r\\\\n|\\\\n)", "\\\n"));`

Again, your servlet has no idea which platform the browser is on (Windows, Mac, or whatever) so unless you're going to look at the user agent header or something you'll always have a problem with one system or the other.

Comment: did you read my update? if i do a simple system.out i can see correct printing with carriage return. I will test anyway this with also the getBytes

Comment: Try open the file sent as attachment with an editor which can show invisible characters something like Notepad++ and check if the new line character exists in the file

Comment: seems working this. thanks for helping i mark as resolution